# Android Task Schedule

Tags: android, scheduled-tasks, scheduling

I'm trying to write an application that will execute a task based on the time of day. Example: it's noon, send a reminder to go to lunch. Anyone know how to accomplish this?

I can schedule tasks based on a timer, but that's not exactly what I'm looking for.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the AlarmManager, specifically: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#set%28int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29